# Serilog - how to change logging granularity without code change

Tags: serilog

I would like to understand if it is possible to change the logging level from Debug to Error on the fly in the production envionment.

FOr instance in Nlog, there is a place in the config file, where i can set the logging granularity.

```
 <level value="Info" />
```

This can be changed on the fly in the UAT environment to get Debug level errors and then after a while, i can change it back to INfo. THis is just a config change and no code change.

How do we handle a similar scenario with Serilog.

```
 Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
.MinimumLevel.Debug()
.WriteTo.RollingFile("log-{Date}.txt")
.WriteTo.LiterateConsole(restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Information)
.CreateLogger();
```

If i need Error logging alone then my config will look like

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
.MinimumLevel.Error()
.WriteTo.RollingFile("log-{Date}.txt")
.WriteTo.LiterateConsole(restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Information)
.CreateLogger();
```

Is it possible to change the minimum level to Error on the fly without making a code change??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Serilog has an [XML app settings provider](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-appsettings) for `App.config`/`Web.config`, and a [JSON configuration provider](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration) for .NET Core's configuration subsystem.

To do this with an `App.config`/`Web.config` file, first install the package:

```
Install-Package Serilog.Settings.AppSettings
```

Add keys to `<appSettings>` in your config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="serilog:minimum-level" value="Debug" />
```

And read this at logger configuration time:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.AppSettings()
    .WriteTo.RollingFile("log-{Date}.txt")
    .WriteTo.LiterateConsole(restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Information)
    .CreateLogger();
```

You can add config entries to write to sinks, enrich with properties, etc. as well. See the documentation at the provider link above for the full set.